# Visual Studio Project rename

Tags: blazor

I've renamed everything I can think of and have no errors, but the launch button still shows the old project name.  How can I update it?  The project is names MusicManager now.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Clean & rebuild the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Show All Files in Solution Explorer.  Properties >  launchSettings.json.  Change the names in the file.

[image]